# Maximum number of SharePoint Major & Minor Version

Tags: versioning

Is there a cap on the number of major and minor version allow for SharePoint? (From what I know, a single major version can have a cap of 511 minor version (draft version).)

Comment: I was thinking in this way - the major version will depend on how much storage space you have. If the document is 5 MB and your space is 500 MB, then the max cap on the number of major version allow is 100, am I right to assume in this way?

Comment: Yes, you are right in that regard since each version is a copy of the file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [SharePoint Server 2010 capacity management: Software boundaries and limits](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx)

> Major versions - 400,000  - Supported - If you exceed this limit, basic file
>   operations—such as file open or save, delete, and viewing the version
>   history— may not succeed.

Comment: Thanks Vedran, by using your link, I checked that for SharePoint 2007 (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28office.12%29.aspx), there was not a clear define of the max limit of Major version except that it mention if versioning is enable for document library, all versions will count towards site quota.

Comment: Please in future include SP version in question when you ask this kind of questions. It makes it lot easier to help you.

Comment: Hi Vedran, sure, not a problem. But anyway, the information you provided is useful as my company is also thinking of migrating to SharePoint 2010.